# Sorting a polymorphic relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have currently set up a poloymorphic relationship by using a **views** table to represent this and it is working

Whenever I try something like this:

```
    public function index($id)
    {
        $bar = Bar::find($id);

        echo count($bar->views);
    }
```

I get the number of results I am expecting and the results are properly viewable with a var_dump as well.

Only when I try to sort the results with a simply where statement like this, I am getting no results at all. I tried multiple where statements but simply nothing happens. No errors.

```
   public function index($id)
    {
        $bar = Bar::find($id);

        $bar->views->where('id', '=', 1);
    }
```

Can I not sort the results that I have gotten returned from the polymorphic relationship or I something else going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) looks very similar with one difference:

```
$user->posts()->where('active', 1)->get();
```

So it looks like you might need to:

```
$bar->views()->where('id', '=', 1); // notice the parentheses after `views`
```